Problema al ejecutar query con pyodbc a Avantage (Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC), retorna rowcount = -1
Estoy generando la conexión sin error pero al ejecutar un query el resultado viene vacio, cursor.rowcount = -1.
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())
>> ['SQL Server', 'Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC']

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC};DataDirectory=X:\STORAGE;DefaultType=FoxPro;ServerTypes=1;CharSet=ANSI;MemoBlockSize=64', autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT CLIENTE FROM TABLA_CLIENTE WHERE CLIENTE = '1003'")
print(cursor.rowcount)

>> -1

Si genero la misma consulta por medio de Advantage Data Architect, me retorna el dato correcto, dejo la imagen de ello:

Cualquier ayuda se agredece,

En principio, acorde a la documentación te va a devolver siempre -1 por cómo se ejecuta (sin memoria).  Sobre la teoría, una vez ejecuta el SELECT, algo tipo cursor.fetchone()[0] debería devolverte el resultado que buscas

Gracias por el comentario @Esei , tienes razón! Me enfoque a que el rowcount deberia traer la cantidad de registros encontrados y me olvide de verificar si el fetchone o all traian algo.
Saludos! Gracias por el aporte.
